# "Multiple definition of X" error in C program

Tags: c

I've been through many of the answers, as you'll see by the modifications to the code, but I'm still getting multiple definitions for all of the functions.

The error is this:

> obj\Debug\usaFilaPreferencial.o: In function `criarFila':
>   C:/Users/wailu/workspace/AED1EP1/filaPreferencial.c:6: multiple
>   definition of`criarFila'
>   obj\Debug\filaPreferencial.o:C:/Users/wailu/workspace/AED1EP1/filaPreferencial.c:6:
>   first defined here

And it repeats for the 7 functions, reporting 15 errors and 2 warnings:

> mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -g  -c
>   C:\Users\wailu\workspace\AED1EP1\filaPreferencial.c -o
>   obj\Debug\filaPreferencial.o
>   C:\Users\wailu\workspace\AED1EP1\filaPreferencial.c: In function
>   'exibirLog': C:\Users\wailu\workspace\AED1EP1\filaPreferencial.c:29:1:
>   warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

I've checked and the functions appear to only be defined once in the header, then implemented in a class that includes said header and finally called in a second class that includes the first one (not the header).

I've also tried to use the `#ifndef / #define` solution some people proposed in other answers, to no avail.

Long story short, my teacher generated three files, filaPreferencial.h, filaPreferencial.c and usaFilaPreferencial.c. We're not supposed to make any modifications to these files, except completing the function stubs generated in filaPreferencial.c (or adding auxiliary functions in this same file).

As I'm very unused to C, it's possible I've done something that's causing this, but I'm at a loss as to what it could be.

filaPreferencial.h

```
#ifndef __FILAPREFERENCIAL_H__ //not present in the original code.
#define __FILAPREFERENCIAL_H__ //not present in the original code.

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define true 1
#define false 0

typedef int bool;

typedef struct aux {
...
} REGISTRO, * PONT;

typedef struct {
...
} FILAPREFERENCIAL, * PFILA;

PFILA criarFila();

int tamanho(PFILA f);

bool inserirElemento(PFILA f, int id, int idade);

PONT removerElementoFila(PFILA f);

PONT removerElementoIdade(PFILA f);

bool consultarIdade(PFILA f, int id, int* resposta);


#endif // __FILAPREFERENCIAL_H__ //not present in the original code.
```

filaPreferencial.c

```
#ifndef __FILAPREFERENCIAL_C__ //not present in the original code.
#define __FILAPREFERENCIAL_C__ //not present in the original code.

#include "filaPreferencial.h"

PFILA criarFila(){
...
}

bool exibirLog(PFILA f){
...
}


bool consultarIdade(PFILA f, int id, int* resposta){
...
}

int tamanho(PFILA f){
...
}


bool inserirElemento(PFILA f, int id, int idade){
...
}

PONT removerElementoIdade(PFILA f){
...
}



PONT removerElementoFila(PFILA f){
...
}

#endif // __FILAPREFERENCIAL_C__  //not present in the original code.
```

usaFilaPreferencial.c

```
#include "filaPreferencial.c"

int main() {
  PFILA f = criarFila();
  PONT prioritario;
  int idade;
  int id;
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 20, 21)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (1)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 30, 23)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (2)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 22, 22)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (3)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 5, 20)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (4)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 50, 25)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (5)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 50, 25)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("ok (6) - registro repetido\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 5, 20)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("ok (7) - registro repetido\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 20, 21)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("ok (8) - registro repetido\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  printf("################# REMOVENDO #######################\n");

  prioritario = removerElementoFila(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Primeiro: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (1)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoFila(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Primeiro: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (2)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoFila(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Primeiro: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (3)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoFila(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Primeiro: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (4)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoFila(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Primeiro: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (5)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoFila(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Primeiro: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (6)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoIdade(f);


  printf("################# INSERINDO NOVAMENTE #############\n");

  if(inserirElemento(f, 6, 1)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (9)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 8, 3)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (10)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 7, 2)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (11)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 5, 1)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (12)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 10, 5)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (13)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 10, 5)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (14)\n");
  exibirLog(f);

  printf("################# REMOVENDO NOVAMENTE #############\n");

  prioritario = removerElementoIdade(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Prioritario: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (7)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoIdade(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Prioritario: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (8)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoIdade(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Prioritario: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (9)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoIdade(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Prioritario: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (10)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoIdade(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Prioritario: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (11)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoIdade(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Prioritario: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (12)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoIdade(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Prioritario: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (13)\n");
  exibirLog(f);

  printf("################# OUTROS TESTES ###################\n");

  if(inserirElemento(f, 50, 20)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (15)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 60, 60)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (10)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 70, 15)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (11)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  if(inserirElemento(f, 80, 70)) printf("ok\n");
  else printf("nok (11)\n");
  exibirLog(f);

  id = 50;
  if (consultarIdade(f,id,&idade)) printf("Elemento encontrado: %i, %i\n", id, idade);
  else printf("Elemento com identificador: %i nao encontrado\n", id);
  id = 40;
  if (consultarIdade(f,id,&idade)) printf("Elemento encontrado: %i, %i\n", id, idade);
  else printf("ok Elemento com identificador: %i nao encontrado\n", id);
  id = 80;
  if (consultarIdade(f,id,&idade)) printf("Elemento encontrado: %i, %i\n", id, idade);
  else printf("Elemento com identificador: %i nao encontrado\n", id);

  prioritario = removerElementoFila(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Primeiro: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (14)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoIdade(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Prioritario: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (15)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoFila(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Primeiro: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (16)\n");
  exibirLog(f);
  prioritario = removerElementoIdade(f);
  if (prioritario) printf("Prioritario: %i, %i\n", prioritario->id, prioritario->idade);
  else printf("Fila vazia (17)\n");
  exibirLog(f);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but don't use symbols with two leading underscores (like e.g. `__FILAPREFERENCIAL_H__`), as those are reserved for the compiler and standard library. You should also learn how to use multiple source files in your project, the correct solution to that is *not* to `#include` them, but to build into separate object files that you then link together into the executable.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I didn't know about the double underscores; thought it was supposed to be used like this. About the includes, I guess the teacher was trying to keep things simple, maybe? I don't know.

Comment: `#include "filaPreferencial.c"` will copy one C file into another one. That is guaranteed to create duplicates. You really wanted to include the .h file instead.

Comment: Wow, the files your teacher provided look quite bad. `typedef` of pointer types, redefinition of `bool` instead of using `stdbool.h`, casting the return of `malloc` . Then (maybe it was you or them) there is a function that is supposed to return a value that doesn't return anything ...

Comment: Thanks, @BoPersson. I ran into an error "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.". But at least it compiled. Now I can handle it, I suppose lol Thanks again!

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement,  Always treat the closing brace '}' as a separate statement.  Suggest treating the opening brace '{' as a separate statement. (cont)

Comment: (cont) 4) provide appropriate horizontal spacing (inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators)

Comment: for flexibility, it is best to separate a struct definition from any `typedef` and/or instance of the struct

Comment: when prototyping functions, if that function does not take any parameters, then the prototype should have `void` between the parens.  Otherwise the compiler will generate the function to take any number and type of parameters (including none)

Comment: the only system header files that should be included inside a header file are those needed for the functions, etc that are prototyped inside that header file.  I.E. these 4 statement: `#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define true 1
#define false 0` should be `#include <stdbool.h>`  and the other header file inclusions should be placed in files that actually use them.

Comment: do not place `include` guards inside C source files, only inside header files

Comment: regarding this kind of code: `struct aux
{
}  REGISTRO, *PONT;`  it is much more understandable (and much less error prone) to use `REGISTRO *`  when needed in the code, rather than  `PONT`   Similar considerations apply to the other typedef'd pointers

Comment: In general, it is best if `struct` definitions always have a `tagname` because most debuggers use the tag name, not the instance name when trying to display the fields within a struct instance.

Comment: variable and parameter names should indicate usage or content (or better, both) names like `f` are meaningless, even in the current context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Bo Persson above may have the right solution for you. You declared all your functions in the header file, and that is all your other source files need to "see" the functions defined in filaPreferencial.c. As such, in usaFilaPreferencial.c you should be including "filaPreferencial.h" rather than "filaPreferencial.c".

Including a source file that is already in the project into another source file, effectively creates two copies of every function in the project. What happens is that when the preprocessor sees `#include "filaPreferencial.c"`, it replaces that statement with the contents of filaPreferencial.c.

Comment: I think Bo Persson above may have the right solution for you. It appears as you declared all your functions in the header file. In usaFilaPreferencial.c you should be including "filaPreferencial.h" rather than "filaPreferencial.c". I apologize for the hasty answer.

Comment: Oh, that really did the trick. I ran into another error, but this one I think I can handle. Thanks!